# error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘QString’ requested

Tags: c++, qt5

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QString h;
    h = "fsdfsdfsf";

    QString j = h.chop(3);
    qDebug() << "j: " << j;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘QString’ requested
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `chop()` is a void function, returns void. I think you meant to do `h.chop(3);  QString j = h;`

Comment: You can use `chopped` to get string after removing n - characters.

Comment: `No member named chopped` says the compiler. @rafix07

Comment: You didn't write which version of QT you are using, in QT5.x this method exists, but not in QT < 5. @Aquarius_Girl

Comment: @rafix07 Qt 5.9.1

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate previous comment, `This function was introduced in Qt 5.10.` from this page http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#chopped. @Aquarius_Girl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the error is that [`QString::chop()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#chop) removes characters from the string for which it is called and does not return anything (returns `void`).

You have two options:

- set `j = h` and then call `j.chop (3)`;
- use [`QString::chopped()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#chopped): `j = h.chopped (3)`.